# Initializing a PriorityQueue with a Comparator with Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

How can I do the equivalent of the below in a constructor, is it possible via Java code?

```
//non DI code
PriorityQueue<Object> queue = new PriorityQueue<Object>(10,
            Comparator.comparing(Object::getOrder)
            .thenComparing(Object::getDate));
```

I want to inject it into a constructor like below

```
@Autowired
public CustomPriorityQueue(PriorityQueue<Object> queue)
{
    this.queue = queue;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Just create a `@Bean` method that returns that `queue`.

Comment: yes thanks, I was confused with the comparator instantiation part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed I needed a @Bean method within a @Configuration class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

}


@Bean
@Primary
public PriorityQueue<WorkOrder> priorityQueue() {

    PriorityQueue<WorkOrder> queue = new PriorityQueue<WorkOrder>(10,
            Comparator.comparing(WorkOrder::getRank).thenComparing(
                    WorkOrder::getDatetime));

    return queue;
}
}
```